# Using binary number sequence to determine which boxes are filled

Tags: algorithm, google-apps-script, binary, bit-manipulation, logarithm

I am struggling with programming the following (with GAS):

I have 14 boxes which are either empty or not and I need to keep track of which boxes are empty. My idea is to use a base2 control value to keep track of the which boxes are empty.

To illustrate I will use an example with only 3 boxes

I figured the following scheme would work:

- All boxes empty: 0 control value
- Only box 1 empty: 1 control value
- Only box 2 empty: 2 control value
- Boxes 1 and 2 empty: 3 control value
- Only box 3 empty: 4 control value
- Boxes 1 and 3 empty: 5 control value
- Boxes 2 and 3 empty: 6 control value
- No boxes empty: 7 control value

I need an algorithm to know which boxes are empty and how to update the control value as boxes are filled and/or emptied.

I assume(d) that there must exist ready to use algorithms for this functionality and hence this sort of use of a base2 series have a name that I can use to google, right?

In case this it the wrong place for this question please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Weird arrangement in my opinion. `All boxes empty: 0 control value`, but `Only box 1 empty: 1 control value`. It would've made more sense if `Only box 1 filled: 1 control value`

Comment: This is called `bitmasks` google it

Comment: Seems like a lot of work. Why not just an array of 14 booleans, filled true, empty false?

Comment: @TheWizEd Speed and memory space

Comment: @TheMaster, I don’t buy it. Are we talking 64k memory and DOS?

Comment: @TheWizEd Or perhaps an embedded system with even less than 64K of memory.

Comment: @JimMischel, but the subject is GAS which means either a PC or mobile device.

Comment: @TheWizEd GAS can be (and is) used in some embedded projects.

Comment: @TheWizEd HA HA like your humor. TheMaster is right of course, because reality is (which I did not mention) that there are many sets of '14' and also of '10'. Since frequent updating is happening there would be a lot of looping using the standard arrray and I am looking for a way to optimize the identity of empty/full containers.

Comment: To those involved, GAS here refers to Google apps script, a custom [tag:v8] based [tag:javascript] engine and NOT Gnu ASsembler. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399396/what-can-be-done-to-prevent-gas-tag-ambiguity

Comment: @TheWizEd Recently ran into [memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752135/how-to-list-all-permutations-without-repetition/73765831#73765831). Bits might help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I second the comment that empty would usually be a 0 bit and full a 1 bit, but I can work with this.)

Just use bitwise operators

```
x & 1 # True if box 1 is empty
x & 2 # True if box 2 is empty
x & 4 # True if box 3 is empty
```

To switch whether boxes are empty or full:

```
x ^ 1 # Switches box 1
x ^ 2 # Switches box 2
x ^ 4 # Switches box 3
```

To make sure a box is empty:

```
x & 1 # Box 1 is empty
x & 2 # Box 2 is empty
x & 4 # Box 3 is empty
```

The only one that is tricky is guaranteeing that a box is full.

```
(x & 1) ^ 1 # Box 1 is full
(x & 2) ^ 2 # Box 2 is full
(x & 4) ^ 4 # Box 3 is full
```

- [Bitwise And(&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND)
- [Bitwise XOR (^)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR)

Comment: Couldn't you also use `x & ~1` to ensure that box 1 is full? (Yeah, 1=empty is weird.)

Answer (score 1):

This is called `bitmasks`. In computer science, a mask or bitmask is **data that is used for bitwise operations, particularly in a bit field.**

You can represent the state of your problem as a `bool` array, something like: `bool is_empty[14];` But this takes `O(N)` memory, where `N` is the number of boxes you have. Instead of using this array you can use the concept of `bitmasks` to represent every box with one bit of a **single** number. Let's take an example three boxes:

```
decimal  binary  meaning
0        000     All three boxes are empty
1        001     Box 1 is full
2        010     Box 2 is full
3        011     Boxes 1, 2 are full
4        100     Box 3 is full
5        101     Boxes 1, 3 are full
6        110     Boxes 2, 3 are full
7        111     All three boxes are full
```

To check if bit `i` is set, you just check if `mask & 1<<i` is not equal to zero.

To turn on bit `i`, you perform `mask = mask | 1<<i;`

To turn off bit `i`, you perform `mask = mask & ~(1<<i)`

To toggle bit `i`, you perform `mask = mask ^ 1<<i`.

A common use of `bitmasks` is generate all subsets from a set of numbers, here is a `C++` to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
  std::vector<int>a{1, 2, 3};
  int n = static_cast<int>(a.size());
  for(int mask = 0;mask < (1<<n);mask++){
    std::vector<int>subset;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
      if(mask & 1<<i){
        subset.push_back(a[i]);
      }
    }
    for(auto &&num: subset)std::cout << num << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```