# Google Sheets check boxs for creating invites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a simple options check list that will then link to a google doc that will be a template invite.

[image]

Based on the tick boxes in Col B i would like to have different options for the URL that will appear in Col D

This seems simple but for some reason is exceedingly complicated.

Comment: Apologies. All done

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Can you provide a more detailed explanation of your objective in your question?  Your sample sheet does not give any more information than your screenshot.

Comment: Based on option A,B,C,D - and which are ticked I would like a different URL to appear in D2 - that is all.

Comment: What if Option A, Option C, and Option D are ticked but not Option B?  What if all are ticked?  What if none are ticked?  Is Option A always going to be ticked if Option B is ticked?  And Option B if Option C is ticked?  Sample sheet should show desired results.  Then someone will be able to better see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Each permutation would link to a different URL

Comment: How many possible URL's do you have?

Comment: `Each permutation would link to a different URL` There are 24 possible combinations of 4 checkboxes - this may explain why `This seems simple but for some reason is exceedingly complicated.`

Comment: Related question: [google apps script n of k permutations without repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74762626/1330560). The answer to this question includes a script `permutations()`. Use this to create the 24 permutations, in an adjacent column add a url for each permutation, and then reference this data array when evaluating the combination of checkboxes.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, as they're hard to copy from. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: `There are 24 possible combinations of 4 checkboxes` Oh dear. Mea culpa The combinations = 16 (2x2x2x2)

Answer (score 2):

**App script solution**

You want to insert a given URL into cell D2 based on the combined values of checkboxes in Column B.

The "trick" here is not the code, but understanding that there is a finite number of combinations of checkbox values (2x2x2x2=16) and assigning a URL to each of those unique combinations.

- refer sheet: `ReferenceData`

The script is straightforward:

- get the CheckBox values and combine them. The answer uses a loop; no doubt there are faster ways to do this.
- get the Reference data values

  - get the "Options" Column as a 1D array
  - use indexOf to find the CheckBox values in the Options column. Again there are likely to be faster ways to do this.
  - use the result from `indexOf` to get the URL
- paste the URL to the "Data" sheet.

---

```
function getInviteURL() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var dataSheetName = "Data"
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dataSheetName)
  var refSheetName = "ReferenceData"
  var refSheet = ss.getSheetByName(refSheetName)

  // get the checkbox values from Data sheet
  var optionData = dataSheet.getRange(2,2,4).getValues()
  // Logger.log(optionData) // DEBUG

  // get the option results
  var options = ""
  for (var i=0;i<optionData.length;i++){
    options = options+optionData[i][0]
  }
  // Logger.log(options) DEBUG

  // get the Reference data
  var refData = refSheet.getRange(2,1,16,2).getValues()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the ref data range = "+refSheet.getRange(2,1,16,2).getA1Notation())
  // Logger.log(refData) // DEBUG
  // get the options as a 1D array
  var refOptions = refData.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  // Logger.log(refOptions) // DEBUG

  // lookup option results in Reference data
  // indexOf returns -1 if the value can't be found
  var result = refOptions.indexOf(options);
  if (result !== -1){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: result = "+result)

    // get the URL
    var urlValue = refData[result][1]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: url = "+urlValue)

    // update URL value to Data sheet
    dataSheet.getRange("D2").setValue(urlValue)
  }
}
```

---

**DATA - Before**

[image: before]

**DATA - After**

[image: after]

**REFERENCE DATA**

[image: referencedata]

Answer (score 0):

**Formula-based solution**

Once the data in sheet:`ReferenceData` has been established, a simple `VLOOKUP` formula can be used to populate the URL.

Enter this is cell D2:
`=vlookup(lower(B2&B3&B4&B5),ReferenceData!$A$2:$B$16,2,0)`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: formula]