# all combinations Google spreadsheet error to show all values

Tags: google-sheets, combinations

I would like to generate all combination from a list a a column A
I would like to return in rows/cells all value for lenght tuple = 12

I got so error because the reesult is too large to be printed.

Then  I try to find a solution print by batch (example 1-20.000 / 20.001-40.000 ...etc...etc)

the formula I used is:

```
=arrayformula( split( 
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
  tocol(A1:A36 & "→" & transpose(
A1:A36)))))))))))))))))))))), "→" ) )
```

the list I want o use is

| Column A |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f |
| g |
| h |
| i |
| j |
| k |
| l |
| m |
| n |
| o |
| p |
| q |
| r |
| s |
| t |
| u |
| v |
| w |
| x |
| y |
| z |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20CSZ.png)

I've read theses 2 questions/responses, but it doesn't helped me so much with my problem

[How to list all permutations without repetition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752135/how-to-list-all-permutations-without-repetition/74160711#74160711)

[Generate all possible combinations for Columns(cross join or Cartesian product)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805885/generate-all-possible-combinations-for-columnscross-join-or-cartesian-product)

I need to know can i print/show the generated values by batch for example or divided in multi spreadsheets.

Thanks with your help.
Max

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are attempting to list all possible 12 character length combinations of lowercase letters and digits, and are having issues due to an error displaying the output. I believe your printing issue stems from the size of the output.

26 letters + 10 digits = 36 options to choose from.

The number possible [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of 12 from 36 is

C(36, 12) = 1251677700, over 1 billion.

Combinations assume order does not matter. If you intend for the order to matter we can do a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) instead:

P(36, 12) = 5.9955562e+17, over a quadrillion.

These numbers are enormous and are beyond the limit of Google Sheets, which has a [cell limit of 10 million cells](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?sjid=6198066102775895335-NA).

Comment: Hello, Yes, I would like to get all combinations with repetition (example: 'aaaaaaaaaaaa')
I would like to know if it's possible to output the result into multi spreadsheet file?
I tried to use array_constrain to limit number of row to show, but i've the same message "value too large..."

Comment: Oh I think I may have misunderstood your question. Do you mean to get the value in column A repeated 12 times? Eg. if A2 is a, get aaaaaaaaaaaa, A3 is b, bbbbbbbbbbbb, etc. If so, you can use the [REPT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en) function =REPT(A2, 12)