# Finding unique combination sets across three columns of data, where order isn't relevant

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, duplicates, permutation

I am seeking to generate a list of combinations without repetitions of data across three columns (Can be anywhere from two to four columns, but for the purposes of this specific example, sticking with three).

I am using MS Excel (latest version I believe)

Each Column has data in it (for purposes of explaining, the data is the alphabet, letter A through to N. So 14 rows).

The data in Column 1 to 3 is the exact same

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A |
| B | B | B |
| *...down too* |  |  |
| N | N | N |

What I am trying to solve is what are the unique three-column data combinations (i.e. without repetitions) that can be generated from these three columns with 14 rows, all with the exact same data.

As an example, a potential row (of many) could be....

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | c |

Of this one row, possible permutations are CAB, CBA, ABC, ACB, BCA, BAC.

Although each are different, for my purposes, 5 of these 6 are considered duplications. The combination of A, B and C, in any order, would be considered one unique combination. The same letters in a different order is a duplication.

This problem could be broken down into two stages

**Stage 1** - Generating a list of all the permutations across the three columns and 14 rows. The output must be keep all the columns separate

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A |
| A | A | B |
| A | B | A |
| B | A | A |

etc...

This would include all permutations with repetitions.

**Stage 2** - Removing duplicates across all these permutations to get the unique combinations (i.e. combinations without repetitions).

Of the c.2,744 rows, a number of them would be considered duplicates (as outlined earlier...CAB and CBA are the same)

This second stage should still maintain all the data in their separate columns. Concatenating is simple to do if required.

Ideally, I would love something that easily solves for both stages, to improve efficiency.

For Problem Stage 1 - I have found a few things in various forums / websites which help, and I believe I have been able to generate.

For Problem Stage 2 - Again I have searched around for solutions and tried various formula's etc. however they don't work

**Update:**
I have taken the approach suggested by DjC, with the results producing the desired outcome alongside providing the flexibility for a novice like me to adapt as required. See picture below for my little proof check -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzwl9.png

Comment: You are right that there are 2,744 *permutations* of the data. For each letter there are 14 choices, hence for 3 letters you have 14x14x14 (=2,744) choices. However, you want the number of *combinations* (e.g. ABC is same as BAC), of which there are 364 (in Excel `=COMBIN(14,3)`. In other languages (e.g. python) there are built-in functions to get all combinations. I don't think it exists in Excel/VBA.

Comment: Do you consider `AAB` a required permutation?

Comment: Terminology really helps. Read up on `combinations` vs `permutations`. Then go deeper and checkout `with/without replacement`.

Comment: If you are going down the road of generating permutations first, have a look at @p.b's wonderfully compact answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546677/creating-a-circular-combination-pattern-from-a-list-of-names-using-excel-formula (not my answer, it's a bit long)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, having 14 possible values (letter A..N) and 3 columns, you have 14 * 13 * 12 = 2184 possible combinations if no letter may occur more than once in one row.

As always 6 (3 * 2 *1) entries are simple variations, you end up with 2184/6 = 384 rows of data.

The following function `CreateAllEntries` will create those entries (using a global array variable `result`). You feed the routine with an array of possible values - in the example it's a list of characters from A..N, but you can fill the array with anything - and with the number of columns you want to fill (eg 3).

The routine will create an array with the data, and you can do what you want with that array - in the example (see routine `FillSheet` that is used as test routine) I have written it to a sheet.

As you can see, the function calls a routine `createEntries` which will call itself recursively, on level per column you want to fill. It iterates through all possible values *that are not already taken*.

Note that I declared the `result` array and the variable `row` as globals for pure lazyness.

```
Option Explicit
Dim result As Variant, row As Long

Sub FillSheet()
    Const colCount As Long = 3

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        
    ' Fill array with possible characters
    ' (Instead of characters, you could fill the array with anything,
    ' Eg Cities, Beveraged, Dates, Names...
    
    Dim possibleValues(1 To 14) As Variant, i As Long
    For i = 1 To 14
        possibleValues(i) = Chr(Asc("A") + i - 1)
    Next
    
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = CreateAllEntries(possibleValues, colCount)
    If rowCount < 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Dump result
    ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
    For i = 1 To colCount
        ws.Cells(1, i) = i & ". column"
    Next
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Resize(rowCount, colCount) = result
    
    MsgBox rowCount & " rows written to sheet " & ws.Name
    
End Sub

Function CreateAllEntries(possibleValues() As Variant, colCount As Long) As Long
    
    ' Calculate result size
    Dim rowCount As Long, i As Long
    rowCount = 1
    For i = UBound(possibleValues) To UBound(possibleValues) - colCount + 1 Step -1
        rowCount = rowCount * i
    Next
    For i = 1 To colCount
        rowCount = rowCount / i
    Next
    
    ' Create an array that will hold the complete result
    If rowCount > Rows.Count Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, this will exceed the possible sheet size of " & Rows.Count & " rows."
        CreateAllEntries = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim result(1 To rowCount, 1 To colCount)
    
    ' Create an array that temporarily stores the values for one row entry
    ReDim colValues(0 To colCount) As Variant
    
    ' fill array (recursive rountine)
    createEntries possibleValues, 1, colCount, colValues
    CreateAllEntries = rowCount

    
End Function


Sub createEntries(possibleValues() As Variant, col As Long, colCount As Long, colValueIndex() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    ' Loop over all "remaining" entries
    For i = colValueIndex(col - 1) + 1 To UBound(possibleValues)
        colValueIndex(col) = i
        If col = colCount Then
            ' We have reached the last column, dump current values into a new row
            Dim j As Long
            row = row + 1
            For j = 1 To colCount
                result(row, j) = possibleValues(colValueIndex(j))
            Next j
        Else
           ' Create entries for the next column
           createEntries possibleValues, col + 1, colCount, colValueIndex
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted. Should the globals be something like Public Row As Long and
Public result As Variant ?

Comment: `Public` is only needed when you want to access global Vars from a different module. Usually, I don't use globals at all but pass them as parameters. But that's a matter of taste (and clean progamming) and doesn't change functionality.

Comment: OK. Just that I got 'Sub or function not defined' at result(Row, j) = possibleValues(colValueIndex(j)) in createEntries when I first tried it, but declaring the variables at the beginning fixed it.

Comment: Upps, that was a Cut&Paste error - I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

With Excel for MS365, you can use a custom recursive lambda function to generate all possible permutations. To do this, open Name Manager (Ctrl+F3) and define a new name called **PERMA** with the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(array1,[array2],
    IF(
        ISOMITTED(array2),
        REDUCE(CHOOSECOLS(array1, 1), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(array1)-1,, 2), LAMBDA(v,n, PERMA(v, CHOOSECOLS(array1, n)))),
        LET(
            a, ROWS(array1),
            b, ROWS(array2),
            HSTACK(
                CHOOSEROWS(array1, TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(, b), SEQUENCE(a)))),
                CHOOSEROWS(array2, TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(a), SEQUENCE(, b))))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Once defined, you can then use the custom `PERMA()` function for **Stage 1** to generate a list of all permutations *with* repetitions. For example:

```
=PERMA(A2:C15)
```

This will output the same number of results as `=PERMUTATIONA(14,3)` (2744 rows).

The formula for **Stage 2** will depend on what you want to be returned...

To generate a list of all permutations *without* repetitions, equivalent to `=PERMUT(14,3)` (2184 rows), use the following:

```
=LET(
    data, PERMA(A2:C15),
    cols, COLUMNS(data),
    FILTER(data, BYROW(data, LAMBDA(r, COLUMNS(UNIQUE(r, 1))=cols)))
)
```

To generate a list of all combinations *with* repetitions, equivalent to `=COMBINA(14,3)` (560 rows), use the following:

```
=LET(
    data, PERMA(A2:C15),
    cols, COLUMNS(data),
    arr, TOCOL(data),
    rowId, TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(, cols), SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)))),
    UNIQUE(WRAPROWS(SORTBY(arr, rowId,, arr, ), cols))
)
```

To generate a list of all combinations *without* repetitions, equivalent to `=COMBIN(14,3)` (364 rows), use the following:

```
=LET(
    data, PERMA(A2:C15),
    cols, COLUMNS(data),
    arr, TOCOL(data),
    rowId, TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(, cols), SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)))),
    unq, UNIQUE(WRAPROWS(SORTBY(arr, rowId,, arr, ), cols)),
    FILTER(unq, BYROW(unq, LAMBDA(r, COLUMNS(UNIQUE(r, 1))=cols)))
)
```

**Example Results:**

[image: perma_examples.png]

Please note, the `PERMA()` function is limited to generating 1,048,576 possible permutations. As such, the maximum number of rows in your dataset cannot exceed 1024 with 2 columns, 101 with 3 columns, 32 with 4 columns, or 16 with 5 columns, and these limits are even less when using the last two COMBIN methods shown above (due to the row limitations of the `TOCOL()` function). Exceeding the limit will return the #NUM! error.

Comment: Thanks DjC - This is simple and perfect! Being a bit of a novice, it is easy to follow and flexible enough should I have more/less columns.

Using both the 'Perma' formula in name manager with the formula to generate a list of all combinations without repetitions, equivalent to =COMBIN(14,3) (364 rows). Has given me the outcome required!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. By the way, I just updated the formula definition for the custom PERMA function to the latest version, which is cleaner and more flexible than the first version I shared. Try it out, if you wish (although the first version does still work well for your situation). Cheers!