# Percentage of data to be extracted in a complex query (DIFF)

Tags: function, performance, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a table with 12 columns. I want to extract 20% of the data for the student in each test.I am using Google sheets.

The data is like

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | test1 |
| name3 | test2 |

The data in other columns is related to the test. But I would like to extract only 20% of the values of student in each test.

For example if there are 10 test for name1 I want to extract only 2 tests values at random

So, if there were 10 values for name1 then I would like only 2 values for name1 with all the rows related to those values extracted at random.)

=LET(name,TOCOL(Data!A2:A,1),
SORTN(
QUERY(Data!A2:G,"where Col1 is not null"),
ROUNDUP(20%*ROWS(name)),,
RANDARRAY(ROWS(name)),))

```
Expected results is mentioned in the link.
I would like 20% of each student. Like there are 8 values for student A and 9 values for student B. I can only get 20% of the total rows. I want 20% of each student. In this case 1.6 (2) and 1.8 (2). So, 4 values 2 each from student A and B. TIA.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),unique(tocol(A3:A,1)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,filter(A3:G,A3:A=c),sortn(Σ,roundup(rows(Σ)*0.2),,lambda(Λ,Λ)(randarray(rows(Σ))),)))))
```

***IMP***: *randomization is auto-triggered if and when the source data in columns A-G is edited/changed*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),unique(tocol(Data!$A$3:$A,1)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,
   arrayformula(chooserows(Data!$A$3:$G,
      ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(sort(sequence(countif(Data!$A$3:$A,c)),randarray(countif(Data!$A$3:$A,c)),1)-1,
          roundup(countif(Data!$A$3:$A,c)*0.2),
          1)
   +match(c,Data!$A$3:$A,0))))))
```

and you can remove the `chooserows` to see that the row numbers are always* unique.

* Almost always. See Explanation.

Note 1: Requires your data to be sorted by student names. ie. All test results of a student are grouped in adjacent rows.

Note 2: If the sheet refreshes too quickly, you may need to use a static database of random numbers as opposed to using `randarray`.

**Explanation**: The strategy is to generate as many random numbers as there are tests for each student and then use the generated numbers to [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585201/how-do-i-make-a-random-permutation-function-in-google-sheets) the tests. Since we are relatively confident that `randarray` will produce unique random numbers, we can use the ordering of the generated random numbers to shuffle the tests and truncate it with `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`. We truncate at 20% many of `countif(data,student_name)` rounded up. `match` identifies the starting rows of each student. (Thus requiring sorted data, which on a second thought can be avoided with `filter` but above is what first came to mind.) `chooserows` can be used to pick out rows specified by row index offset. And we use the combination of `reduce` and `vstack` to vertically concatenate results for each unique student name. `tocol` usage to coerce the Google Sheet functions to behave properly with empty rows.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is equally good.